Approximations when applying conservation of momentum to massive objects
I was solving the following problem, when I had this doubt, even though I solved it correctly I didn't quite understand the approximation I used to get the answer.

A small ball of mass $m_0$ is suspended from a thread of length $l$ attached at the top of a pole, which is mounted on a block $A$ of mass $m_1$. The block $A$ and the ball both are moving with a velocity $u$ when the block $A$ strikes another block $B$ of mass $m_2$ and sticks to it. If the ground is frictionless, find the minimum velocity $u$ so that the ball can move on a complete circular path. Assume that the blocks $A$ and $B$ are much heavier than the ball.

The diagram of the problem is as follows:

I solved the problem as follows, first I applied momentum conservation in the horizontal direction to obtain the following equation
$$(m_1 + m_0)u= (m_1 + m_2 + m_0)v$$
where $v$ is the velocity of the two blocks after collision. Now, as it is given that $m_1, m_2 \gg m_0$,
$$v = \frac{m_1}{m_1 + m_2}u.$$
Since the minimum velocity required to complete a circle is $\sqrt{5gl}$, by looking in the frame of the blocks we see that
$$u - v \geq \sqrt{5gl} \\ u \geq \frac{m_1 + m_2}{2}\sqrt{5gl}.$$
This is the correct answer; however my question is whether this answer is only true when $m_1, m_2 \gg m_0$. Why does this approximation fail, assuming it does, when the mass of the ball gets appreciably large?
Any help in this issue would be highly appreciated!

First of all, I have to point out a little mistake in your first equation. Since the ball is attached to a thread and it is vertical-downward, the ball's velocity remains as $u$ right after the collision. So the first equation writes:
$$m_{1}u=(m_{1}+m_{2})v$$
hence we have $$v=\frac{m_{1}}{m_{1}+m_{2}}u$$
even if we don't do any approximation.
Then we've come to the real problem about how approximation affects the motion of the ball. If $m_{1},m_{2}$ are large enough that $m_{0}$ is neglectable, we won't need to consider how the ball's motion will affect the motion of the two blocks, since the momentum of the ball is too small that any change of its momentum will not cause appreciable variation on A and B's movement.
However, if $m_{0},m_{1},m_{2}$ are in the same order of magnitude, the variation in momentum of the ball will influence A and B and you can't simply view the frame of blocks as inertial frame. Then the velocity $v'$(relative to the blocks frame) of the ball at the highest point should be given by :
$$m_{0}u+Mv=m_{0}(V-v)'+MV$$
$$\frac{1}{2}m_{0}u^{2}+\frac{1}{2}Mv^{2}=\frac{1}{2}m_{0}(V-v')^{2}+\frac{1}{2}MV^{2}$$
where $M=m_{1}+m_{2}$ and $V$ is the velocity of blocks when the ball is at the highest point.
I'll just skip the calculation here. But you can easily see that if we don't neglect $m_{0}$, it does make great difference to this problem.
In addition, we can directly consider the limitation of $m_{0}<<m_{1},m_{2}$ in the equations above, and we'll get $v=V$ which indicates that if $m_{0}$ is small enough, it won't influence the blocks' movement at all and we can view blocks frame as a inertial frame and your solution will make no mistake.

I don't think the OP made a mistake. You can calculate the center of mass of the body composed of mass A and the pendulum, and treat the situation as a collision between mass $m_0+m_1$ and mass $m_2$. Conservation of momentum must hold with respect to the horizontal axis.

Well, if the OP was considering the center of mass, then he had already made a approximation as he notes $v$ is the velocity of the two blocks after collision. But it seems the first approximation was made by him after the first equation had been writen (or so I thought).

Actually it seems that indeed with respect to the $x$ axis to begin with we don't need to treat both pendulum and block $A$ as one combined mass because they do not form a single rigid body. It is only when the pendulum starts swinging, thus exerting forces on block $A$ that this really becomes relevant... see also my answer here.

Besides, we also have to make another approximation if we use the center of mass frame—— if $m_{0}$ is not small enough, the suspension point of the thread will have an additional displacement in both x and y directions relative to the center of mass frame so extra terms (inertia force) should be brought in and that will make the problem even trickier.

I was incorrect in bringing up the COM idea at all with regards to the initial conditions. The right way to treat the initial condition is as though block A and the pendulum are moving independently. Apologies!

Never mind! Your comment made me reflect on something about center of mass which I hadn't considered when I first saw this question, and it did help me to try to solve this problem in a different way by using COM frame.
